# SQL select from 4 tables in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is the problem, I have this 4 tables:

Books

```
  idbook ISBN   title   sinopse   pages  lang   code   year  edition  idedit
     1    EC2   somet     thing      34    ES     Ec2   2011     1       1
     2    EC3    more    things     545    ES     Ec4   2012     2       2
     3    EC4    lots   ofthing     323    EN     Uk1   2014     1       1
```

Editorial

```
idedit     name      country          web
     1     Pearson      USA        www.pearson.com
     2     Pretince     UK         www.pretince.com
```

Author

```
idaut      name       country     bio
  1        George       USA       lorem ipsum
  2         Jeff        UK        dolor sit amet
```

Authory

```
 idbook       idaut       order
  1             1           2   
  2             2           5
  3             1           7
```

So, I need a view that shows only the elements that match ES lang, ordered by year. for each book you need to show: the year, title, ISBN, edition, name of editorial and name of author.
no problem with name of editorial and order but I dont know how to get the name of author.
Authory is a table that is in mid of book and author.
This is my code so far:

```
create view `INFORMATICS` as
(select l.year, l.title, l.isbn, l.edition, e.name 
from books l
inner join  editorial e on e.idedit=l.idedit
where lang = 'ES'
)
```

The select until this point is good, but how can I add the author name? like a.name
To get a table like this:

```
year    title   ISBN    edition   editorial_name    author_name
2011   somet    EC2       1          Pearson           George
2012    more    EC3       2          Pretince          Jeff
```

Comment: Nobody ever needed a view :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you have to join `authory` with `books` to get author id `idaut` and then join `authory` with `author` to get the author name.

```
create view `INFORMATICS` as
(select 
    l.year, 
    l.title, 
    l.isbn, 
    l.edition, 
    e.name, 
    a.name 
from books l
inner join  editorial e 
on e.idedit=l.idedit
inner join  authory ar 
on l.idbook=ar.idbook

inner join  author a
on ar.idaut=a.idaut

where lang = 'ES'
order by l.year
)
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was the triple inner join that I was thinking, It worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like a normal table

But you need another column in your view and that is idbook

```
create view `INFORMATICS` as
(select l.idbook ,l.year, l.title, l.isbn, l.edition, e.name 
from books l
inner join  editorial e on e.idedit=l.idedit
where lang = 'ES'
)
```

and then SELECT and INNER JOIN

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATICS i 
    INNER  JOIN  authory au 
      ON i.idbook=au.idbook
    INNER JOIN  author a    
      ON au.idaut=a.idaut 
 WHERE a.name ='Arthur';
```

As Strawberry pointed correctly out 
[views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html) have some restrictions including unable to use Indexes, so that an be slower as when you make this directly

Comment: Note that this (probably) cannot use an index